# Cascading Column Selections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column, dropdown, cascading

I am trying to find a way to make it so that when a User selects from a drop down option of "Category", based on their response, specific options will appear in the drop down for the next column "Services".  Is this possible using out of the box features?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, there is an outstanding jQuery library called [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) that has a function to help with cascading columns. If you can't use script, there is an option available using [InfoPath](http://koobarspoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/cascading-drop-downs-with-infopath-2010.html).

Comment: Thank you this is perfect and support seems really involved on his site. Thanks!